# Select entity from database if that throws an error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I migrated MySQL database to SQL Server. My project uses Entity Framework. I have database class

```
public class Database : DbContext
{
    public Database() { }

    public Database(DbContextOptions<Database> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<AccessGroup> AccessGroups { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=my_server;User ID=user;password=password;database=suz;Initial Catalog=suz;Trusted_Connection=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;Encrypt=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
    }
}
```

And AccessGroup class

```
[Table("accessgroups")]
public class AccessGroup
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool CanSubscribe { get; set; }
    public bool CanSeeHisTickets { get; set; }
    public bool CanSeeCompanyTickets { get; set; }
    public bool CanSeeAllTickets { get; set; }
    public bool CanEditTickets { get; set; }
    public bool CanDeleteTickets { get; set; }
    public bool CanSeeServiceComments { get; set; }
    public bool CanRegisterUsers { get; set; }
    public bool CanSelectTopic { get; set; }
    public bool CanEditUsers { get; set; }
    public bool CanSelectUrgency { get; set; }
    public bool CanTakeTickets { get; set; }
    public bool CanAssignTickets { get; set; }
    public bool CanFinishTickets { get; set; }
    public bool CanMoveTickets { get; set; }
}
```

but when I try to get it from the database it throws an error:

```
database.AccessGroups.ToList()
```

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): invalid object name "accessgroups".

Here is the query it performs

```
 SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[CanAssignTickets], [a].[CanDeleteTickets], [a].[CanEditTickets], [a].[CanEditUsers], [a].[CanFinishTickets], [a].[CanMoveTickets], [a].[CanRegisterUsers], [a].[CanSeeAllTickets], [a].[CanSeeCompanyTickets], [a].[CanSeeHisTickets], [a].[CanSeeServiceComments], [a].[CanSelectTopic], [a].[CanSelectUrgency], [a].[CanSubscribe], [a].[CanTakeTickets], [a].[Name]
  FROM [accessgroups] AS [a]
```

[there is my database configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zsIj.png)

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: The error says that the table doesn't exist. Either you're connecting to the wrong database or forgot to create the table

Comment: Probably something with the schema. The table has some non-default one

Comment: Post the table schema as *text*, not links to images.

Comment: Looks like it has schema `suz`. `[Table("accessgroups", Schema = "suz")]`

Comment: Using `nvarchar(max)` for the name is a bad idea, unless you expect names with millions of characters. `nvarchar(max)` is a special type with special, slower storage, meant for large text up to 2GB

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How can I post it as text? stackoverflow prohibits me from adding pictures and replaces them with links

Comment: `CREATE TABLE suz.accessgroups (ID int PRIMARY KEY,.....` You can generate the script by right clicking on the table and selecting `Script Table As > CREATE To`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is defined in the `suz` schema. You need to specify that either in the `Table` attribute or in `OnModelCreating`, eg:

```
[Table("accessgroups", Schema="suz")]
public class AccessGroup
```

Comment: thanks it works, but why `database=suz;Initial Catalog=suz;` causes no effect?

Comment: Schemas aren't databases. A database can contain multiple schemas. Only MySQL treats the two terms as if they were the same thing. In Oralce, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, schemas are subdivisions inside the database, with their own permissions

Comment: This is probably what caused me such difficulty

Comment: BTW `Initial Catalog` and `Database` are synonyms in the connection string.

Comment: If you download the [SQL Server sample databases](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/databases/wide-world-importers) you'll see that schemas are used to organize tables into Sales and Purchasing schemas. Different users can be given permission to different schemas based on their roles. You can still JOIN tables across schemas without any cross-database penalty